# How to get Apache2.2 load the SQLite3 Class from PHP?

Tags: windows, apache, sqlite, php

I am currently trying to get a working PHP environment on Windows, but for some reason Apache isn't able to execute e.g. `print_r(SQLite3::version());`, but says `Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\index.php on line 8`, while *php.exe* prints perfectly correct output.

In *php.ini* I only load `extension=php_sqlite3.dll`, nothing else. In *httpd.conf* I got `PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/"` which enables Apache to handle normal php commands like `echo phpinfo();`.

Does anybody know what I have to do so SQLite3 works through Apache, too?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Nevremind, solved it myself: The default line `extension_dir = "ext"` for Windows installations had to be changed to the absolute path, in my case `extension_dir = "c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext"`. This made it all work!

Comment: And when you run `phpinfo()` you see that SQLite3 module is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Run your `phpinfo()` and check if extension is loaded, if not, check `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` and `Loaded Configuration File` to see where it is looking for `php.ini` and which file is loaded. If it is correct, set `display_startup_errors` in your ini to on and look into apache error log to see if there are problems with loading some extension. I would guess that prior to loading sqlite you will need to load php_mbstring.dll

Comment: Uhm, the file path is "C:\Windows", though the file loaded is "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini", which is correct. Is it normal for those two value to differ? I'll try the display_startup_errors and come back here in a moment...

Comment: the error in apache's error log: "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SQLite3' not found in C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\index.php on line 8
". Doesn't look helpful to me :(

Comment: also, searching php.ini for "mb_string" returns no results

Comment: it's `php_mbstring.dll` actually.